# Find string that is not between specific html tag

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I'm being required to use regular expressions to parse HTML. I do realize regular expressions are bad for HTML matching.

I would like to find a specific string and evaluate whether or not its between two strings.

In this example `&reg;` must be immediately between `<sup>` and `</sup>`

Example:
`<sup>&reg;</sup>`

I believe this would involve using negative lookaheads and lookbehinds. My first thought would be:

`(?<!<sup>)&reg;(?!<\/sup>)`

Unfortunately this fails as I don't believe you can do a lookahead and lookbehind in this combination.

Just using the negative-lookahead does work and is probably good enough for my purposes...

`&reg;(?!<\/sup>)`

...but I'd like to know if it's possible to combine a lookahead and lookbehind in this way. Or is there another technique I should be using?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your initial regex (i.e. `(?<!<sup>)&reg;(?!<\/sup>)`) is correct, as demonstrated in the example usage at https://www.debuggex.com/r/WyY9y0Zq2Krz_3Xm

However, it works in Python and PCRE, but not in Javascript (you can check by choosing each of them in the dropdown).  Javascript does not have negative  lookbehind support.